# Why can I not locate a .csv file when using LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE?

Tags: mysql, database, csv, mamp

I'm using MySql version 5.6 on a Mac running MAMP.  I've set my document root to user/Desktop/Sites/Rankings.  I'm trying to upload a CSV file into a table using the following code:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'teams.csv' INTO TABLE Teams
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r'
IGNORE 1 LINES
(team_id, team_location, team_name, team_abbrv);
```

I keep getting the following error message:

```
ERROR 2 (HY000): File 'teams.csv' not found (Errcode: 2 - No such file or directory)
```

I've tried changing a bunch of things based on research done on this site with no luck.  I've confirmed read/write permissions on the file and and made sure local_infile is ON.  I'm starting to wonder if I'm not pointing in the right direction.  When I use LOCAL, does that mean I should be putting my .csv file in the same document root file (Rankings) that I've set up in MAMP?  That's what I've done, but it still doesn't seem to be working.  I'm going crazy!  Thank you for the help.

Comment: Try: `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/user/Desktop/Sites/Rankings/teams.csv' ...`. `If given as a relative path name, the name is interpreted relative to the directory in which the client program was started.`, see [13.2.6 LOAD DATA INFILE Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/load-data.html).

Comment: Specify the full path. MySQL usually starts looking in totally the wrong place. It's also a "Mac". I don't know where people get the idea to call it a [MAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address).

Comment: still getting the No such file or directory error message ...

Comment: I've tried specifying the full path with no luck.  and yes, I should've used Mac.  sorry about that.

Comment: @wchiquito okay so I'm going to ask a dumb question.  'If given as a relative path name, the name is interpreted relative to the directory in which the client program was started.'  The client program in my case would be MAMP, correct?

Comment: @tadman I guess I'm struggling with the full path.  I've used '/user/Desktop/Sites/Rankings/teams.csv' without any luck...

Comment: Is `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` executed from the MySQL command line?.

Comment: @wchiquito  yup executed from the terminal command line

Comment: Try: `mysql> \! ls /user/Desktop/Sites/Rankings/teams.csv`. What do you get?.

Comment: @mizDawg Unless your username is literally `Desktop` then that won't work. If you're curious about your path, `pwd` in the shell will tell you.

Comment: @wchiquito I get 'No such file or directory.' after trying:    \! ls /user/Desktop/Sites/Rankings/teams.csv

Comment: Then, your file doesn't seem to be on that path.

Comment: @wchiquito any method on how to find the exact path needed?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem myself and was not liking a full path to a file, kept saying file not found.

What worked for me is I found the data directory and put the CSV file in there and it would load the file locally from that directory.

```
/usr/local/var/mysql/dbname/file.csv

LOAD DATA INFILE 'file.csv' INTO TABLE dbname.table FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

Hope it saves someone the 30 minute headache I had.